# Why locale received from Google Places API is always null

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google place API on android application. When place is selected, I receive Place object. From that object, I want to use Locale. But everytime I am getting Locale null. Am I missing something?

I am able to get name, address, lat, long from that place object.

Also, is there any other method to find the locale for that location?

Is it somehow related to Google API key? I am using API key which I used for google maps. I am using it in manifest in following manner:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="myKeyWith39Letters" />
```

Comment: Please post your code.